# Sorting variable

Tags: bash, sorting, unix

i have problem with sorting in variable.

I work with Bash and with NSH console.

I load to variable, biggest folders in my OS:

```
vdirList=$(nexec -e "find /etc -type d -size +1k -print0 | xargs -0 du -h --max-depth 3 --time --time-style +'%F %T %z' 2>/dev/null| sort -h -k1 2>/dev/null| tail -7 | sed -n '$ ! p' | uniq -c | tac | sed 's/^/BAORES: /'") 
vdirList+="\n"
vdirList+=$(nexec -e "find /usr -type d -size +1k -print0 | xargs -0 du -h --max-depth 3 --time --time-style +'%F %T %z' 2>/dev/null| sort -h -k1 2>/dev/null| tail -7 | sed -n '$ ! p' | uniq -c | tac | sed 's/^/BAORES: /'")
vdirList+="\n"
```

This is output:

```
BAORES: 3 22M 2017-05-05 14:53:20 +0300 /etc/selinux/targeted
BAORES: 2 22M 2017-05-05 14:53:20 +0300 /etc/selinux
BAORES: 1 13M 2017-05-05 14:53:20 +0300 /etc/selinux/targeted/modules
BAORES: 2 1.9G 2018-12-20 05:49:04 +0200 /usr/lib
BAORES: 3 1.3G 2018-12-20 05:48:55 +0200 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
BAORES: 1 445M 2018-12-20 05:49:04 +0200 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
```

I want sort this files by 3 column i use this command:

```
dirList=$(nexec -e "echo \"$vdirList\" | sort -hrk3 | head -n 10")
```

But my output is:

```
BAORES:  3  22M   2017-05-05  14:53:20  +0300  /etc/selinux/targeted
BAORES:  3  1.3G  2018-12-20  05:48:55  +0200  /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
BAORES:  2  22M   2017-05-05  14:53:20  +0300  /etc/selinux
BAORES:  1  445M  2018-12-20  05:49:04  +0200  /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
BAORES:  1  13M   2017-05-05  14:53:20  +0300  /etc/selinux/targeted/modules
BAORES:  2  1.9G  2018-12-20  05:49:04  +0200  /usr/lib
```

Can someone help with this? Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I can confirm the weird behaviour with `LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8`. Under the C locale, it seems to work correctly:

```
$ input='BAORES: 3...
...
.../i386-linux-gnu'
$ LC_ALL=C sort -k3,3hr <<< "$input"
BAORES: 2 1.9G 2018-12-20 05:49:04 +0200 /usr/lib
BAORES: 3 1.3G 2018-12-20 05:48:55 +0200 /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
BAORES: 1 445M 2018-12-20 05:49:04 +0200 /usr/lib/i386-linux-gnu
BAORES: 2 22M 2017-05-05 14:53:20 +0300 /etc/selinux
BAORES: 3 22M 2017-05-05 14:53:20 +0300 /etc/selinux/targeted
BAORES: 1 13M 2017-05-05 14:53:20 +0300 /etc/selinux/targeted/modules
```

What also worked was to specify the separator explicitly:

```
sort -t' ' -k3,3hr
```

but I find the locale setting more reliable.

Comment: Yes, it work, if it have this output in file, but i need work with this in variable.

Comment: `LC_ALL=C sort -k3,3hr <<< "$variable"`

Comment: Still same output :-/

Comment: @Destrem: Updated to show exactly the steps that work for me.